# 再配置とローダーの関係は？

Tags: c++, c

リンカやローダについて勉強していると、「メモリに展開する」や「再配置」などという用語が出てきます。

はじめ「メモリに展開する」も「再配置」もどちらも同じ意味かと思ったのですが、
どうやら同じ意味ではなく、「メモリに展開」がまさしくメモリに配置すること。
「再配置」は、その配置したメモリのアドレスとシンボルの対応を管理すること。
と思ったのですが、この認識であっていますでしょうか？

となると、前後関係がわかりません。メモリに展開した結果、たまたま今回配置されたアドレスを覚えておくことを「再配置」としているのか、その逆で、先にアドレスを決定したうえで、そこにローダーが配置しにいくのか。

（あまり本質問と関係ないですが、リンカのことをローダとも呼ぶ場合もあるようです）

再配置とロードの関係性について前後関係（処理の順番）を中心に教えてください。

Answer (score 3):

概ねその理解であってると思います。用語には厳密な定義はありませんし、筆者それぞれの用語定義で語られているでしょうから、複数の筆者の文章を見比べたときに１つの語に複数の意味があったり、複数の語が同じ意味を持ったりはよくあることです。

その上で補足するならば、「再配置」は英語の**relocate**、**relocation**の訳語の可能性があり、「位置をずらす」だけでなく「ずれた位置に合わせて調整する」というニュアンスも含んでいるかなと思います。
そのため、あるモジュールをメモリに展開したら、そのモジュールを参照しているモジュールのアドレステーブルを更新するという行為が「再配置」という用語に込められているかなと。

Answer (score 0):

> メモリに展開した結果、たまたま今回配置されたアドレスを覚えておくことを「再配置」としているのか、その逆で、先にアドレスを決定したうえで、そこにローダーが配置しにいくのか。

その理解は間違ってます
オブジェクトは、（未確定な）アドレスの場所を空けたデータです。
リンカ／ローダは、配置アドレスから、その空けているアドレスを計算し実際のアドレスを算出、その場所に計算結果を当てはめ、その結果をバイナリとして展開します。
順序なぞありません